# Can you use a string to getinstance of custom setting?

Tags: customsetting

I am trying to get the values from a custom setting for more than one instance of the setting. If I replace 'placeholder' with shay or austin it works.

```
list<string> names = new list<string>{'shay', 'austin'};

for(integer i=0; i < 2; i++){
     string placeholder1 = '\''+ names[i] +'\'';
     sendgridsettings__c sgs1 = sendgridsettings__c.getInstance(placeholder);

     string placeholder2 = names[i];
     endgridsettings__c sgs2 = sendgridsettings__c.getInstance('\''+placeholder+'\'')



*********************THIS WORKED BELOW******************
 tring placeholder1 = names[i];
 sendgridsettings__c sgs1 = sendgridsettings__c.getInstance(placeholder);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just get a value by name like this:

```
list<string> names = new list<string>{'shay', 'austin'};
for (string name : names) {
    sendgridsettings__c sgs = sendgridsettings__c.getInstance(name);
    // Use the setting instance
}
```

You don't need to add single quotes: they are only used when you define a string constant such as `'shay'`.